# How to parse simple JSON Array in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I've been wondering how to parse JSON Array in android ?

I've a json object like this:  `[{"ID":"1","email":"email@mail.mail","password":"password"},{"ID":"2","email":"test@test.com","password":"passward"}]`

but I cannot find how to parse it, I want to access data so i could have the first mail, or the second id.

I've try around 40 differents solutions, but no luck.

Last time I tried something it was this:

```
private void showJSON(String json){
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);
            String JsonString = jArray["ID"];
            tv.append(JsonString);

        } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

but it expected an array and not a json array. I still haven't found how to convert it into array.

I've also tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonobject.getString("email");
}
```

but getJSONObject doesn't exist.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "but getJSONObject doesn't exist" -- [sure it does](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject%28int%29). Presumably, `jsonarray` is not a `JSONArray`. You may be happier using Gson, Jackson, or other more modern JSON parsing libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void showJSON(String json){
    try{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

       String id[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
       String email[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("email");
     }
     }
    catch (JSONException e) {
                // Log.d("JSONException", e.toString());
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use gson to deserialize the array back into an object. https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 0):

It is simple when using Gson:
First, you create class User:

```
public class User
{
private String ID;
private String email;
private String password;
}
```

Then create UserStringJson class:

```
public class UserStringJson{
ArrayList<User> userArrays = new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

Finally, Using gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
UserStringJson userStringJson = new UserStringJson();
userStringJson = gson.fromJson(jsonstring,
                    UserStringJson.class);
String email = userStringJson.getuserArrays().get(0).getEmail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Custom Object `User` :

```
public class User {
    public String ID;
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

---

Use this class into `showJson()` method :

```
private void showJSON(String json) {
    try {
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            User user = new User();
            user.ID = jsonObject.getString("id");
            user.email = jsonObject.getString("email");                 user.password = jsonObject.getString("password");
            userList.add(user);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
JSONArray arr= new JSONArray("json string");
for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
JSONObject obj= arr.getJSONObject(i);
// Now use this obj to get desired values.
int ID= Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("ID"))// or use getInt method
// Similarly you can do for the rest.

}
```

Hope it helps.